# "Create Translation Package" via API?

Tags: variations, multilingual, api, machine-translation

On multilingual SharePoint websites you can export/import the content with `XLIFF` files. Is this functionality somehow available via the API?

Multi-language website background here:
[Create a multi-language website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-multi-language-website-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6?CorrelationId=ffca4dbd-6758-4157-9272-3314fde6f548&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc337460838)

And since we're on the topic, is it possible to add another icon to that ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, it uses Microsoft Translator API
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx

Edit: Found this APi: 
Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices namespace, which is located in Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices.dll that you can use, check the MSDN link below for more details, but i think that it only translate documents and not XLIFF msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/jj163145.aspx

Comment: Right, but I'm not looking for a why to translate my pages with a machine translation system, but for an API where I can kick off the XLIFF file generation. Sharepoint has the option to send content to the Microsoft Translator, but I need to implement this for a human translation agency.

Comment: Indeed, I find this API, there is Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices namespace, which is located in Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices.dll that you can use, check the MSDN link below for more details, but i think that it only translate documents and not XLIFF 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/jj163145.aspx